# Memory error with app termination in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, uiimage, out-of-memory, viewdidlayoutsubviews

I have `setBackgroundImage` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. It calls `viewDidLayoutSubviews` infinitely. As a result memory is increased with app termination. What am I doing wrong? It happens only in iPhone 5s and the same code works fine in iPad Air and iPhone 4s.

```
[_hosStartDateBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cal23.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//_hosStartDateBtn is a button added programatically in viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

Comment: Why not try moving the setBackgroundImage code outside the viewDidLayoutSubviews ?

Comment: yes it works if i add the same code in viewWillAppear..what is the issue if i put it in viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Comment: don't add _hosStartDateBtn   to view in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: Probably what @Shan said. I'm guessing when you addSubview inside viewDidLayoutSubviews(), it triggers another viewDidLayoutSubviews() call, resulting in an infinite loop as you mentioned. Probably not wise to put those code in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: OK..I have added my code in ViewWillAppear..it is working fine but scroll content size is not getting set properly in ViewWillAppear but works fine in viewDidLayoutSubviews